# SQL query of my table rights given through a role?

Tags: sql, data-dictionary

I need to build a query that returns the tables I have access to because of rights given to me through a role with the data dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL this is a simple query on the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROLE_TABLE_GRANTS view.

```
SELECT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROLE_TABLE_GRANTS WHERE GRANTEE = 'THE_ROLE_NAME'
```

Some database systems do not support this view, but have alternative views containing the roles and the granted privileges. Among open source databases, [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org) supports a large number of INFORMATION_SCHEMA views, including the above.